# Python - How to get range index efficient

Tags: python, numpy, performance

I want to get the efficient way to locate range index for every element in an array.

```py
import numpy as np


def range_index(arr, starts, ends):
    _idx_starts = np.searchsorted(starts, arr, side='right')
    _idx_ends = np.searchsorted(ends, arr, side='left') + 1
    _idx_starts[_idx_starts != _idx_ends] = -1
    return _idx_starts
```

in which:

arr is sorted array to be indexed.

starts is sorted start index array.

ends is sorted end index array.

starts and ends don't have overlap (`np.c_[starts, ends].flatten()` is sorted)

it works like

```
_d = np.linspace(0, 20, 11)
_ranges = np.asarray([
    (1, 5),
    (7, 9),
    (12, 16)
])
_idx = range_index(_d, _ranges[:, 0], _ranges[:, 1])
print(np.c_[_idx, _d])
```

and output is

```
[[-1.  0.]
 [ 1.  2.]
 [ 1.  4.]
 [-1.  6.]
 [ 2.  8.]
 [-1. 10.]
 [ 3. 12.]
 [ 3. 14.]
 [ 3. 16.]
 [-1. 18.]
 [-1. 20.]]
```

but when arr is sorted, How can I make it more efficient?

Comment: `np.unique` has optional returns that might be of use.

Answer (score 0):

Defining the side parameters, 'left' and 'right' to increase the efficiency of np.searchsorted by reducing the number of times you make comparisons. You could use the built-in "timeit" module to benchmark np.searchsort and binary search 'bisect' to determine which method is more efficient

Comment: Thanks for  answer my question, because arr, starts, ends is large arrays, so I think np.searchsorted is more efficientive than bisect. But my question is how to make searchsorted_sorted more efficient....